# Apply Formula to Cell Using a VBA defined Array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

There are definitely easier ways to achieve what this code is trying to do, but I created a simplified code to show what I am trying to achieve. Basically I want to perform calculations on lots of data and I don't want to have to have to add that to the worksheets.

So basically I need to run formulas like sum, averageifs, etc. in a worksheet through using an Array that I defined in my Macro.  At this point I can't figure out how to turn this array, containing 5 values, into a "=sum(  )" function.  Thanks in advance for your help!

```
Sub ArraySum()

Dim numbers(5) As Double
Dim E As Double

For I = 1 To 5
    E = Cells(I, 1)
    numbers(I) = Cos(E)
Next I

Range("b1").Formula = "=sum(" & numbers & ")"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear why you'd want to do it this way, but:

```
Sub ArraySum()

    Dim numbers(1 To 5) '<<<
    Dim E As Double

    For I = 1 To 5
        E = Cells(I, 1)
        numbers(I) = Cos(E)
    Next I

    Range("B1").Formula = "=SUM(" & Join(numbers, ",") & ")"

End Sub
```

but then you might as well just do:

```
Range("B1").FormulaArray = "=SUM(COS(A1:A5))"
```

Comment: Ya it does seem unclear in my mind as well. My end goal would be achieved if I could just do something like this formula within excel, is there a way to do this?               =averageif(cos(i2:i5), ">0", cos(i2:i5))

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "within excel" ?  - on a worksheet you can just use the array formula in my second example (use `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` when entering it on the sheet)

Comment: Ya I mean on a worksheet.  Right, I can do your example with the ctrl+shift+enter, but it's not letting me do it for averageif(cos(a1:a5), ">0"). Do you know what the problem could be? Appreciate your help.

Comment: Not sure you can use an array formula with averageif

Comment: Can fake it with something like `=SUM((COS(A1:A5)>0)*COS(A1:A5))/SUM((COS(A1:A5)>0)*1)`

Answer (score 0):

Another way if you don't need the formula to actually be in that cell:

```
Range("b1").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(numbers)
```

Edit: If you haven't set `Option Base 1` then `Dim numbers(3) As Double` will create a 4-element array numbers(0),...,numbers(3) since the default is `Base 0`. I would recommend using `Dim numbers(1 to 3) As Double` rather than relying on the Base option.

Edit 2: You either have forgotten `Dim I` in your example or don't use `Option Explicit` which is highly reccomended!

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be an equation in the worksheet? You could just get the total and put it there:

```
Sub ArraySum()

    Dim numbers(1 To 5) '<<<
    Dim E As Double

    For I = 1 To 5
        E = Cells(I, 1)
        numbers(I) = Cos(E)
    Next I

    Range("B1").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(numbers)
End Sub
```